# Can I make Phone Calls with my Xtouch X709 Tablet?

Tags: tablet, calls, hardware

I am getting an [Xtouch X709](http://uae.souq.com/ae-en/xtouch-x709-tablet-white-7-inch-android-4-0-8gb-wifi-dual-camera-4979071/i/) in a few days. It is running on Android 4.0.

Can I insert a SIM card in this tablet and use it to make phone calls?

Comment: That spec page does not indicate anywhere that it has a SIM card slot (meaning also that it has no cellular chip), so how were you intending to use it? It says it supports a USB 3G modem, but those generally don't make phone calls directly; you'd need VoIP.

Comment: Without cellular service, you're going to need a VoIP client that can hook into the plain old telephone service. Skype and Vonage arose two such clients, but you'll generally have to pay for access to POTS. It's usually not that much, though.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you have to insert  a sim card and try to call because I have x708 tablet  .

Comment: Do you mean, it works on your tablet? Or are you trying to say that it doesn't work on yours?